# SAM command failing with: ImportError: cannot import name AliasedEventEmitter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-serverless, serverless-application-model

I am running a SAM template through AWS CodeBuild using a `buildspec.yml` file
I believe that this issue is caused by pip installing a default python 2.7 version of the `aws-sam-cli` package. I'm not that familiar with how to `pip install` the `python3` version of a package. Here is a snippet of my `buildspec.yml`:

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Pre-Build Phase started - SAM Deployment"
      - alias python=python3
      - pip install --upgrade pip
      - pip install aws-sam-cli # install the sam cli
      - USER_BASE_PATH=$(python -m site --user-base) # save the path to the user's local packages folder to a variable (as opposed to the global packages folder)
      - export PATH=$PATH:$USER_BASE_PATH/bin # add the user's local packages folder to PATH
      - sam --version # verify "sam" can now be called
  build:
    commands:
      - sam package --runtime python3 --template-file ${INPUT_FILE} --output-template-file ${OUTPUT_FILE} --s3-bucket ${S3_BUCKET} # package the template to an S3 bucket
...
```

Has anyone ever run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone revisiting this question I figured it out. Below is my revised `buildspec.yml` snippet. I had to install the awscli package with pip3.

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Pre-Build Phase started - SAM Deployment"
      - ls -ltr # list directory contents from oldest to new
      - sudo apt-get update
      - sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
      - sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli
      - apt-get update > /dev/null # get list of package updates from 
    repositories
      - apt-get install jq -y > /dev/null # install 32-bit JSON processor
      - jq --version # check JSON processor installed / which version
      - wget -q https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64 # get 64-bit JSON processor
      - chmod +x jq-linux64 # make executable
      - mv jq-linux64 $(which jq) # make "jq" alias point to 64-bit jq
      - jq --version # verify jq points to new version
      - alias python=python3
      - pip install aws-sam-cli # install the sam cli
      - USER_BASE_PATH=$(python -m site --user-base) # save the path to the user's local packages folder to a variable (as opposed to the global packages folder)
      - export PATH=$PATH:$USER_BASE_PATH/bin # add the user's local packages folder to PATH
      - sam --version # verify "sam" can now be called
  build:
    commands:
      - sam package --template-file ${INPUT_FILE} --output-template-file ${OUTPUT_FILE} --s3-bucket ${S3_BUCKET} # package the template to an S3 bucket
```